# Mi programa en C se salta un bucle for al aumentar el número de columnas de un array

Tags: array, c, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un programa que genera aleatoriamente ceros y unos y los guarda en un array (excepto la primera fila que son todos ceros) al que se le introducen el número de filas y columnas por pantalla, así cono el factor que calcula la proporción entre ceros y unos.
Una vez creado el array quiero pasarlo a un archivo txt para poder dibujarlo con un programa.
La generación del array lo hace sin problemas, y cuando termina y pasa a la parte en que lo guarda en el archivo de texto sucede una cosa muy rara que he visto depurando el código.
Si pruebo con 15 columnas o menos me genera el archivo de texto sin problemas, pero si intento generar un array de 20 columnas o más el programa genera el array, pero después se salta el bucle `for` que debería escribir los elementos en el archivo de texto.
No consigo saber por qué funciona con 15 columnas y con 20 se salta el bucle.
Os pego el programa para que veáis lo que he hecho.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tam = 0, N = 0, m = 0;
    float fac = 0.0;

    printf("Introducir número de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    printf("Introducir númaro de filas: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Introducir el factor: ");
    scanf("%f", &fac);

    int POR[N][tam];

    srand(time(0));

    FILE* por;
    por = fopen("por.txt", "w");

    double lim = 1.0 / ((1.0 / fac) + 1.0);

    for (int j = 0; j < tam; ++j) {
        POR[m][j] = 0;
    }
    for (m = 1; m < N + 1; ++m){
        for (int k = 0; k < tam; ++k){
            if ((((double) rand()) / ((RAND_MAX) + 1.0) > lim)){
                POR[m][k] = 1;
            } else{
                    POR[m][k] = 0;
                }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        fprintf(por, "%d\t", 0);
    }
    fprintf(por, "\n");

    for (int j = 1; j < N + 1; ++j){
        for (int k = 0; k < tam; ++k){
            fprintf(por, "%d\t", POR[j][k]);
        }
        fprintf(por, "\n");
    }
    fclose(por);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo de "se salta el bucle" me suena más a que hay un *undefined behavior* y simplemente hay un crash del programa (el programa acaba en error).

Comment: No hay ningún mensaje de error, ni alertas ni nada al compilar. Y he visto que se "salta" el bucle al depurar. Símplemente, cuando llega al ````for```` no entra y no escribe los datos en el archivo de texto. Y tampoco explicas por qué funciona con 15 columnas y no con 20.

Comment: Tendría que revisarlo porque llevo mucho tiempo sin usar c, pero si no recuerdo mal, la inicialización de un array como lo que haces para POR puede ser problemática porque deben saberse los valores en tiempo de compilación. ¿Has probado a usar malloc para reservar memoria?

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y me da un segmentation fault en tiempo de ejecución. Aparte de que se ven otros problemas (que pueden ser la causa). ¿Cómo has depurado el código?

Comment: Gracias por echarme una mano. Con el debugger en CLion. Pasando línea por línea para ver cómo se ejecuta el programa, pero no sé demasiado, y de lo único que me he dado cuenta es de que para tamaños del array de más de 20 columnas al llegar la ejecución al bucle que tendría que escribir el archivo txt, en lugar de entrar salta y se va al final.

Comment: @Vacendak Era un problema con los índices, se estaba accediendo a una posición de memoria que no le pertenecía y lanzando un fallo de  segmentación  que causaba que el programa se terminara antes de entrar en  el bucle de escritura (porque fallaba al final del bucle que genera los datos). No sé por qué no te salía  el mensaje al depurar, pero una vez  corregí eso, ya funcionaba con 15, 20 y 50 sin problemas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Alvaro!!! Ahora funciona perfectamente.  Había puesto esos índices para evitar la primera fila de ceros, pero no he sabido ver ese error al depurar. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ejecuto el código de la pregunta  sin ningún cambio recibo el siguiente error:

> Segmentation fault 11

Que se debe a que se está intentando acceder a una posición de memoria que no corresponde al programa (algo *común* con arrays). Mirando el código hay dos puntos que llaman la atención:

```
for (m = 1; m < N + 1; ++m){
```

y

```
for (int j = 1; j < N + 1; ++j){
```

En C los arrays empiezan en 0 y llegan hasta tamaño menos 1, algo  que haces en todos los bucles menos en esos dos que vas desde 1 hasta tamaño. Debes cambiarlos para  que sean de 0 a tamaño menos 1.

Corrigiendo esas dos cosas, el programa ya funciona sin problemas (indicando las dos líneas que se han modificado):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tam = 0, N = 0, m = 0;
    float fac = 0.0;

    printf("Introducir número de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    printf("Introducir númaro de filas: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Introducir el factor: ");
    scanf("%f", &fac);

    int POR[N][tam];

    srand(time(0));

    FILE* por;
    por = fopen("por.txt", "w");

    double lim = 1.0 / ((1.0 / fac) + 1.0);

    for (int j = 0; j < tam; ++j) {
        POR[m][j] = 0;
    }
    // fila modificada
    for (m = 0; m < N; ++m){
        for (int k = 0; k < tam; ++k){
            if ((((double) rand()) / ((RAND_MAX) + 1.0) > lim)){
                POR[m][k] = 1;
            } else{
                    POR[m][k] = 0;
                }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        fprintf(por, "%d\t", 0);
    }
    fprintf(por, "\n");

    // fila modificada
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
        for (int k = 0; k < tam; ++k){
            fprintf(por, "%d\t", POR[j][k]);
        }
        fprintf(por, "\n");
    }
    fclose(por);
    return 0;
}
```

Con esos dos cambios, el código ya funciona sin problemas (aunque pensaba que iba a fallar por cómo se inicializa `POR`, pero parece que es algo que se ha cambiado  y se puede hacer... aprendí algo nuevo).

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la ayuda de Alvaro Montoro he conseguido que el programa funcione y, de paso, lo he retocado para integrar los comandos que escriben el archivo txt al mismo tiempo que se va generando el array, por lo que se reduce el número de líneas y queda un poco más elegante.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tam = 0, N = 0, m = 0;
    float fac = 0.0;

    printf("Introducir el número de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    printf("Introducir el número de filas: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Introducir el factor: ");
    scanf("%f", &fac);

    int POR[N][tam];

    srand(time(0));

    FILE* por;
    por = fopen("por.txt", "w");

    double lim = 1.0 / ((1.0 / fac) + 1.0);

    for (int j = 0; j < tam; ++j)
    {
        POR[m][j] = 0;
        fprintf(por, "%d\t", POR[0][j]);
    }
    fprintf(por, "\n");

    for (m = 0; m < N; ++m){
        for (int k = 0; k < tam; ++k){
            if ((((double) rand()) / ((RAND_MAX) + 1.0) > lim)){
                POR[m][k] = 1;
            } else{
                POR[m][k] = 0;
            }
            fprintf(por, "%d\t", POR[m][k]);
        }
        fprintf(por, "\n");
    }
    fclose(por);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amigo Vacendak, ya llevas tiempo en el sitio y deberías saber como funciona: si una respuesta te parece correcta o te ayudó, **vótala positivo**. Si fue la que te sirvió o mas te ayudó, **acéptala**. Un saludo :-)